# Firebase paging data. Is it possible?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I have a function which basically reads data from firebase. I am trying to implement paging. Please see what i tried. I have seen other posts on this website but they are not very clear.

```
  getFormData(pageSize:number,pageIndex:number,af:AngulrFireDatabase) {

      Try1: Returning all records
      ---------------------------- 
         return this.af.list('/forms').skip(pageIndex*pageSize).take(pageSize);


      Try2: Not sure how to use the previous page last key value to pass to load the next page data. 
      -----------------------------

            return this.af.list('/forms', {
                query: {
                    orderByKey: true,
                    limitToFirst:pageSize 
                    // How to skip the first few records here. for example if the page index is 2 then i have to ignore the first 2 pages data.
                }
            })

  }
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated with a basic code example. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can't skip a specific number of records. But you can tell Firebase at which item to start by specifying `startAt: "keyAtWhichToStart"`.

The reason for not having offset based queries is that they don't work well in the context of realtime updates, which is what the Firebase Database was designed for.

I recommend also reading some of the many [previous questions on pagination in the Firebase Realtime Database](https://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+firebase+database+pagination).

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. But why do we have skip and take functions available? I read all these posts already and i knew this answer as you previously suggested in another post.
I was expecting firebase could do something more related to paging.

Comment: "The reason for not having offset based queries is that they don't work well in the context of realtime updates, which is what the Firebase Database was designed for."