# How to retrieve x entries from firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm fairly new into using firebase and I'm trying to keep the number of downloads under 10 Gb every month. In my app, I often retrieve data singularly via this URL

`https://project.firebaseio.com/screenshots.json?orderBy='$key'&equalTo='-LmfNVR1voBLGGkEdX26'`

A feature in my app that I find expensive is the read and write and I'd like to keep it in the free tier for the time being. I thought the solution might be to use the `limitToFirst` parameter but this gets only the x amount of entries from firebase.

The solution that I'm hoping for is one that would allow me to have a fixed amount of entries and have the option in my app to load the next x amount of entries if needed. This way, downloads would be lessened and be less expensive than it needs to be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you want to use [startAt](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/retrieve-data#section-rest-filtering) to specify which record to skip to along with limitToFirst to query for a particular "page" of data.

Comment: Note that Firebase's pagination is based on knowing the anchor document/node, and not based on offsets (as most databases do). See my answer from earlier today for some good links on that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57570929/is-there-a-way-to-get-a-firebase-element-from-a-certain-index/57575045#57575045